# How do I update multiple users on Blazor Server-Side?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

Suppose I want a UI where users in a group have a synchronized view. Imagine a group-chat application, where everyone in the group should see the exact same messages.

When a user posts a message to the group, the entire group needs to receive it.

With JS, I might use SignalR Groups, and have the front-end generate a SignalR event with a message is posted. The server-side hub would then send that message out to the group.

On Server-Side Blazor, since all the users' states are already on the server, how would I coordinate updating the UI of groups of users on Blazor?

Comment: Perhaps you could subscribe each user to an event that gets fired when any user submits a message, and that event would update the individual users components?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was trying to achieve something similar. After a while, I discovered a way of doing this. Kyle's answer helped me figure it out.

You must create a class, let's call **Messenger**, which has an Action property, and a method that invokes this Action once called

```
public Action OnMessage { get; set; }
public void AddMessage(string message)
{
  Text = message;
  OnMessage?.Invoke();
}
```

In the razor component, inject the Messenger. Also, you should set an event to the OnMessage property, and then call StateHasChanged in order to tell the view that it can update

```
@inject Messenger messenger
// rest of component here, and then the code block 
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  messenger.OnMessage += () =>
  {
    // do something with the messenger.Text here
    InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
  };
}
```

Don't forget, on your Startup class, add the class Messenger as a Singleton in order to have it available for injection

```
services.AddSingleton<Messenger>();
```

I hope that is what you were trying to achieve, and it can help others as well.
Cheers.

Comment: This sure have gave me perspective but won't it just keeps adding on to the `OnMessage` delegate a new anonymous action every time a user opens a new circuit or just reloads the component?