# Implementing a global notification system in blazor server with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to implement a notification system that notifies specific users depending on their roles or permissions in Blazor Server Side .NET 5 with SignalR.
I've already implemented Identity Authentication and Authorization.

In my `MainLayout.razor` page i've implemented a `HubConnectionBuilder` as follows:

```
private HubConnection _hubConnection;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //SignalR
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(MyNavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/hub"))
        .Build();

    _hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
    {
        Toaster.NotificacaoGlobal(user, message);
        StateHasChanged();
    });

    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

I've also created a TestHub.cs where i have a few methods as follows:

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs i've added:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("/hub");
            });
```

and

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

My ideia was to store the connectionId and UserId on the `OnConnectedAsync()` and then on the method `await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);` filter the user with something like `Clients.User(userId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);`

I've tried to use both `Context.UserIdentifier` and `Context.User.Identity.Name` inside `OnConnectedAsync()` method and both return null. Some said to use the `[Authorize]` atribute in the `TestHub.cs` but that gives me an exception: `HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).` on `await _hubConnection.StartAsync()`

Implementing IUserIdProvider did not resolve the problem as some suggested:

```
public class IdBasedUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
 {
      public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
      {
           //TODO: Implement USERID Mapper Here
           //throw new NotImplementedException();

           return connection.User.FindFirst("sub").Value;
      }
 }


services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, IdBasedUserIdProvider>();
```

I'm new to blazor and SignalR and might be something that I'm not aware.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

As asked i'm going to clarify the problem i'm having as best as I can.

**What do I need?** A system for sending push notifications to specific users.

**What have I done?** Tried to implement SignalR to send those notifications through SignalR

**The struggles**: After implementing the `TestHub.cs` class and the initializer on `OnInitializedAsync()` on my razor page I was unable to map the identity user with the connectionId in SignalR.
What I need is some clarification, if possible, whether am I making a mistake implementing SignalR, if SignalR makes sense in this cenario or if is there any other tool or system that makes more sense.

I hope I clarified enough. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and clarify the problem and your question at the start. At the moment you seem to be asking for a design review.

Comment: I've updated my question on Edit 1 where I try to clarify my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update multiple users on Blazor Server-Side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696970/how-do-i-update-multiple-users-on-blazor-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to use both Context.UserIdentifier and Context.User.Identity.Name inside OnConnectedAsync() method and both return null.

create a custom IUserIdProvider

```
public class UserNameProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name?? "";
    }
}
```

and add this in your programm.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, UserNameProvider>();
```

then Context.UserIdentifier should not be null anymore

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", Context.UserIdentifier, message);
    }
}
```